# E: The value 'saucy' is invalid for APT

Tags: synaptic

I tried to upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 (beta2). It was mainly successful, but there was an error concerning libpostproc52. I didn't pay too much attention at the time (I know, bad idea, but there were other things going on). By and large, the upgrade is fine, except I have two problems with package management.

1) with synaptic I get:

> E: The value 'saucy' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
>   E: _cache->open() failed, please report.

I've cleaned the software sources to only include Canonical & independent sources. With synaptic in non-super user mode, vlc-nox shows as broken.

2) with apt-get -f install, I get:

> dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpostproc52_6%3a0.git20120821-4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
>   libpostproc52:amd64 6:0.git20120821-4 (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with libpostproc52 which has multiple installed instances

I think the second is related to some combination of VLC and ffmpeg. I've tried various combinations of -f, clean, remove, etc. with apt-get to no avail.

I can't figure out if these two are related or not, but if I can solve the first problem, then I can probably solve the second.

The real question is who or what is generating the 'saucy' reference in synaptic?

Any suggestions?

---

problem 1) SOLVED: edit (change "saucy" to "trusty") /root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf

problem 2) SOLVED: "dpkg -P fubar" to delete unruly package; unrelated to 1).

Apparently, I cannot label the title as solved!